# How to format jsf tags using s:formattedText

Tags: jsf, seam

I am trying to display an image using `<s:formattedText value="#{image}"/>`. Image value actually corresponds to `image="<h:graphicImage value=\"/img/bird.png\"/>"`. Now while formatting seam throws a warning message

```
[UIFormattedText] Seam Text parse error: invalid element 'h'
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? s:formattedText is designed to display text in a rich-text format, not display images, which is what you're asking it to do.